# MOSFET Switch for LED

Tags: mosfet, switches, mosfet-driver

[image: Mosfet switch circuit]

I want to use this circuit for my LED. Can someone explain to me how to choose the right value for Rin and Rgs? It would help if you explain that with the equation.

Comment: Welcome! Please simulate the circuit with Rin=0 and no Rgs. What does it look like? Increase Rin. What happens?

Comment: What is it for? Pure on/off or PWM dimming?

Comment: Pure on/off, with logic 'on' at 3.3 V

Comment: Your first task should be to choose a suitable MOSFET. Then you can think about the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FETs used for this type of work are "logic-level", meaning they have a gate-source voltage (Vgs) threshold (turn-on voltage) that is compatible with typical logic families.

For example, the popular [2N7002 n-FET](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/2N7002.pdf) has a Vgs threshold of 2.5V (max). Thus, a 3.3V logic input straight to the gate (no voltage divider) will turn the FET on. There is no harm to the FET if the gate goes *above* 3.3V some: the allowable max gate-source voltage for this device is +/-30V.

So, the 'right' values for Rin and Rgs are zero and infinity, respectively.

For driving LEDs I've tended to migrate to the [BSS138](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/bss138-d.pdf), which is compatible with 1.8V logic levels (Vgs threshold 1.5V max). It still works fine for 2.5, 3.3 5 or 12V logic levels you might encounter, but has a lower max Vgs of +/-20V.

Now, why would one use a voltage divider on a FET input? You need one If the FET has a lower max Vgs than the drive signal. If for example you used the BSS138 with a 24V logic signal control, the gate voltage needs to be limited to +/-20V to not damage the device. So you'd use something like Rin=5k and Rgs=20k to achieve that limit.

This comes up more with larger power FETs (HEXFETs, TrenchFETs and so forth) which sometimes have lower Vgs max of 10 ~ 20V.